# I can't access my admin page after changing main url

Tags: wordpress

I have change the main URL of my wordpress theme.
I accessed `Admin area => Settings => and change my URL from : 
www.sampleURL.com to www.sampleURL.com/?page_id=2`

and now every time I enter `www.sampleURL.com/wp-admin` i get directed to `www.sampleURL.com/?page_id=2`

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Access your MySQL Database Directly

This can normally be done through phpMyAdmin, or through your host's Control Panel (cPanel, Plesk, etc)

2) Replace the "www.sampleURL.com/?page_id=2" with "www.sampleURL.com" using the SQL Query:

```
UPDATE `wp_options`
SET `option_value` = 'http://www.sampleURL.com'
WHERE `option_value` = 'http://www.sampleURL.com/?page_id=2'
```

3) Refer to the [Wordpress Tutorial on setting your Front Page](http://en.support.wordpress.com/pages/front-page/)